# Weird thing on sharedPreferences while loading the highest score

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreferences` to store and load the highest score on my game. The problem that I found is that when I close the emulator from the 'X' mark it didn't save the highest score, but if I firstly put the app in the background and then close it (within the emulator or from the 'X' mark) it will save and load the best score. Here is the code that I use:

```
//save the highscore
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("BEST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("key", best);
editor.commit();

//load the highscore
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("BEST", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
best = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
```

*note*: I have tested the game on two acutal devices ( *LG Optimus L2* and *Samsung Galaxy A3*) and on both of them everything works normally. It is something that i shouldn't worry about?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I had to use "Clean Project" after I renamed the folder of the project directly and from here I encountered some errors. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether your score gets saved depends on where you run your code to save it (which looks completely fine). If you, for example, save it in the `onStop()` method of an Activity, then putting it in the background will save it properly.

Shutting down the emulator by closing its window probably kills it quite violently, in which case it can very easily be the case that your app doesn't receive the lifecycle callbacks it normally does, it just gets terminated immediately, hence your code that would save to `SharedPreferences` doesn't get to run. On a real device this sort of immediate shutdown would be the equivalent of shutting down the phone by holding the power button or taking out the battery, which is not something you can prepare for.

TL;DR: this seems normal, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I understand what's going on. I already try to shut down the actual device but everything was ok, the highest score saved. :)